# How to access Windows Phone folders from a Gmail Wrapper App

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, gmail, windows-phone

I have created a Gmail Wrapper Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) application using Webview. When I try to compose an Email and try to add attachments, file picker is not displayed and nothing happens.

However when I use the Internet Explorer and login to the same Gmail account and click on Attach, the file picker is shown with different options to choose the attachment from.

I have enabled the required capabilities in App Manifest, however the file picker is not shown in the Wrapper application.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosted browser (`WebView`) cannot show the native file picker. You'd need to proxy the request somehow and show the picker from C# for example. But, as you don't own the gmail source code, making the proper surgical changes would be difficult (and subject to be changed).

Comment: I was trying to listen to Script Notify event of the webview, but it was not getting through that event :(

Comment: I'd expect this to be extremely fragile ultimately.